# Exchange 2010 - Access is denied when accessing mailbox from OWA

Tags: exchange-server-2010

I can create the mailbox fine - no errors.
When I try to access the mailbox from OWA I get this message:

```
Access is denied. 
The Active Directory resource couldn't be accessed. This may be because the Active Directory object doesn't exist or the object has become corrupted, or because you don't have the correct permissions.
```

If I wait a few hours, it works.

The mailbox was created locally on the Exchange server's database.
There are no replication issues between the child-domain (where the EX is) and the parent domain. But since the mailbox is local, why should it need the parent domain?

Any ideas what to look for?